# jQuery linking script files not working

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make some jQuery animations for my page, but doesn't work at all.
Note that I'm not asking for the animations, just for the whole jQuery itself.
Here you have the code...

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/global.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/general.js"></script>
    <title>Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="main_title">TextText</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          alert("hi");
       });
```

Path of files (* means folder):

*styles (inside: general.css)

*img

*js (inside: general.js and jquery-3.2.1.min.js)

index.html

I've checked sometimes the path of the files and are actually ok, so i tried using an URL for the jquery library but still the same.

**Clarification**: any jQuery code i try doesn't work; again not asking for any animation.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit1**: `type="text/javascript"` removed.

**Edit2**: Problem solved, read my answer. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Right Click on the page. Click Inspect. Click Console in the window that pops up. Refresh the page. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Yes, i get one: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: For which file?

Comment: instead of "../js/general.js"  use "js/general.js"

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but you don't need to add `type="text/javascript"` to your `script` tags. Save yourself a few bytes :). As @AdityaRao says, your path is incorrect. `../` means "go up one folder from where index.html is". It appears your js folder is in the same root folder as index.html, so no need to go up one level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I thought that the path of the scripts were from the .css, not the .html.
Only had to change the general.js path to js/general.js.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove http from your jquery link.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("hi");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Website</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="main_title">TextText</h1>
</body>
</html>
```